# Transforming access of fields

Tags: java, reflection, java-bytecode-asm

I need to set a field to a value a couple of times a second, I currently use reflection to do this and ASM to modify an external library.

Would it be better to use ASM (or reflectasm) to change the acess level of the field to public?

Reflection seems fast and efficient as it is at the moment.

Comment: i wonder how you use asm to make field to public when they are loaded

Comment: “Reflection seems fast and efficient as it is at the moment.” then I don’t understand your question.

Comment: I was just wondering if ASM or reflectasm would make it any more effcient or faster

Comment: ASM seems to be a more efficient choice but if you are satisfied with java reflection why would you want to change ? I don't know what is your target application but sometimes a very efficient framework like ASM does not make a huge difference. It depends on your application and your needs.

Comment: There's nothing ASM can do what Reflection can't do (in the background). Since loading another library like ASM, and the code generation process itself cause additional overhead in the first place, you need to have a strong reason to assume that there's something to improve significantly to compensate that overhead before burden yourself with ASM. Since you said that Reflection performs well, it's unlikely that you can improve it. ASM is no magic.

Comment: I'm using ASM at the moment to do some bytecode modification to library @Holger